# I can't add DB to ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC, and I have a problem.

I created my database in SQL Server Express, using SQL Server Management Studio.
I created a new ASP.NET project, so I want do add that database into the project.

I'm going:

- `App_data` (folder) -> right click -> Add -> Existing item, find my DB on disk and when I click "Add", I got alert window "Access is denied".

What should I do?

Please help, ty :)

Comment: If you created the database with Management Studio, it's been created **on the server** (where it really belongs) - so you cannot just "add it" as a `.mdf` file to your project. Instead - **use it on the server!** Just use the connection string to your server (`server=.\SQLEXPRESS;database=YourDatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;`) and stop worrying about trying to use "free-floating" `.mdf` (which are a nightmare to use on soooo many levels......)

Comment: Thx for your time, ill try that :) I just have to make connection string and everything else worke like DB is in app_date folder?!